# matlab imshow not working with certain tiff files

Tags: matlab, tiff, imshow

I get the following errors when trying to run imshow with some tiff files:

```
??? Error using ==> imageDisplayValidateParams>validateCData at 114
Unsupported dimension

Error in ==> imageDisplayValidateParams at 31
common_args.CData = validateCData(common_args.CData,image_type);

Error in ==> imageDisplayParseInputs at 79
common_args = imageDisplayValidateParams(common_args);

Error in ==> imshow at 199
  [common_args,specific_args] = ...

Error in ==> CellArea at 6
imshow('A1 x20.tiff')
```

I initially stored the image data in a matlab variable using `imread` and when that didn't work with `imshow` I used it to just get the image directly with the filename; the error messages are the same.

The problem images I'm trying to analyze are 1032x778 tiff files. I made a sample tif image using Paint and the function has no problems with it. Does anybody know what is causing these errors and how to get the image to display? Thanks

Here is the infinfo output for one of the images, as requested

```
                 Filename: 'A1 x20.tiff'
              FileModDate: '14-Oct-2013 15:49:26'
                 FileSize: 3211714
                   Format: 'tif'
            FormatVersion: []
                    Width: 1032
                   Height: 778
                 BitDepth: 32
                ColorType: 'truecolor'
          FormatSignature: [73 73 42 0]
                ByteOrder: 'little-endian'
           NewSubFileType: 0
            BitsPerSample: [8 8 8 8]
              Compression: 'Uncompressed'
PhotometricInterpretation: 'RGB'
             StripOffsets: 8
          SamplesPerPixel: 4
             RowsPerStrip: 4.2950e+009
          StripByteCounts: 3211584
              XResolution: []
              YResolution: []
           ResolutionUnit: 'None'
                 Colormap: []
      PlanarConfiguration: 'Chunky'
                TileWidth: []
               TileLength: []
              TileOffsets: []
           TileByteCounts: []
              Orientation: 1
                FillOrder: 1
         GrayResponseUnit: 0.0100
           MaxSampleValue: [255 255 255 255]
           MinSampleValue: 0
             Thresholding: 1
                   Offset: 3211592
```

doing x = imread('A1 x20.tiff') and then whos x gives

```
Name x
Size 778x1032x4
Bytes 3211584
Class uint8
Attributes
```

Comment: You have to first use `imread` on the file. Type `x = imread('A1 x20.tiff');` and then `imshow(x)`. If it doesn't work, type `whos x` and tell us what you get

Comment: what does `iminfo('A1 x20.tiff')` print out?

Comment: Daniel - Do you mean imfinfo? Updated the original post with that information

Comment: @LiamFisher is it possible your tiff file is storing several frames? what is the output of `whos x`? try `imshow( x(:,:,1:3) )`

Comment: Imshow with that input works! Can you explain more about the multiple frames?

Answer (score 5):

For some reason your tiff file has four channels (nothing to do with multiple frames): `size(x,3)==4`. I guess the fourth is an alpha-channel.
`imshow` can display either gray scale images, indexed images (with `size(x,3)==1`) or true-color images (with `size(x,3)==3`). Your image had 4 channels and thus `imshow` failed.
Asking `inshow` to work only on the first three channels made the trick:

```
 >> imshow( x(:,:,1:3) );
```